# jquery datatable to highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, datatables

"Hi everyone.
I was wondering how I could pass, dynamically, jquery datatable values to highcharts from the code below. Variables like xAxis and the 2 yAxis".
I do have more than 3 columns I should say, but not included here.
mySql feed data to php who returns value as json format for datatable. Surely Highcharts can use this info without calling mysql again.

```
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Generated kW</th>
                    <th>Efficiency %</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#chartdaytable').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../../php/ChartDayTable.php",
        "bPaginate":true,
        "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "aoColumns": [
            { mData: 'date' } ,
            { mData: 'day_energy' },
            { mData: 'efficiency' }
        ]
    });
    $('#chartgen').highcharts({
        data: {
            table: 'chartdaytable',
            endColumn: 2,
        },
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy',
        },
        xAxis: [{
            //categories: 'some data',
        }],
        series: [{
            name: 'Generation',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 0,
            //data: 'some data',
        }, {
            name: 'Efficiency',
            type: 'spline',
            yAxis: 1,
            //data: 'some data',
        }]
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you add `console.log(y_values1)` , `console.log(y_values1)` and `console.log(y_values2)` output  in post.

Comment: The console log return and "undefined" message.

Comment: If I change to this:
var x_values = table[0];
Then I get:
<table id="chartdaytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" aria-describedby="chartdaytable_info">

Comment: can you add output of `var data = table.rows().data();console.log(data)`

Comment: I've tried that before. It returns that table.rows is not a function.

Comment: Please provide us with the content of the #chartdaytable table and create a working JSFiddle demo. As for getting data from tables, you can use Highcharts data module (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module). Example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed.

Comment: This is the data table<br/>
                      <table id="chartdaytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Generated kW</th>
                        <th>Efficiency %</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                  </table>

Comment: Your table is empty. I assume that you are getting data from the ChartDayTable.php file. Could you provide it as well? I prepared a simple example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/zhhofxus/.

Comment: Ok. Here is the php script. I do have more than 3 columns but only looking to draw the 1rst 3.  

    <?php
    $sql1=
    $result1=mysqli_query($conn, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $data=array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result1) ) {
 $data[] = array(
 'date' => $rows[0],
 'day_energy' => round($rows[1],3),
    'efficiency' => round(((($rows[1] / 5.940) * 100) / 5.940), 2),
    );
    }
    $return = array(
 "sEcho" => 1,
 "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
 "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
 "aaData"=>$data);
    echo json_encode($return);
    ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example with static datatables. This will give some idea to get started. Check comment in snippet, if some doubt please comment

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  var data = table.rows().data();

  var categories = []; //creating array for storing browser type in array.
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    categories.push(data[i][0])
  }
  var count = {}; //creating object for getting categories with count
  categories.forEach(function(i) {
    count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
  });
  //console.log(count)
  var series_data = []; //creating empty array for highcharts series data
  var categores = []; //creating empty array for highcharts categories
  Object.keys(count).map(function(item, key) {
    series_data.push(count[item]);
    categores.push(item)
  });
  //console.log(series_data)
  plotChart(series_data, categores)
});

function plotChart(series_data, categores) {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: categores
    },
    yAxis: {

      title: {
        text: 'Count'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Browser',
      data: series_data
    }]

  });
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/gstpyuzg/) Demonstration

**Update**
This is server side sample which populate the chart after loading data in datatables.

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cbEfqLwFaq?indent=2';

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': {
      type: 'POST',
      'url': url,
      'data': function(d) {
        console.log(d.order);
        return JSON.stringify(d);
      }
    },
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
      data = table.rows().data()

      var categories = []; //creating array for storing browser type in array.
      var series_data = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        categories.push(data[i][0])
        series_data.push(Number([data[i][5].match(/\d/g).join("")]))
      }

      plotChart(categories, series_data)
    }
  });

  //
  //
  $('#reload').click(function(e) {
    table.ajax.reload();
  });

  //    
});

function plotChart(categories, series_data) {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: categories
    },
    yAxis: {

      title: {
        text: 'Count'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'person',
      data: series_data
    }]

  });
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="reload">reload table</button>
<button class="toggleCols" data-column="0">First Name</button>

<br>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<br>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/rgwahx2m/) Demo

Comment: Thanks for that. But table.rows is not a function in my case.  
Here is a console log for table is this can help  
>"#chartdaytable", $: DataTable/this.$(sSelector, oOpts), _: >DataTable/this._(sSelector, oOpts), fnAddData: >DataTable/this.fnAddData(mData, bRedraw), fnAdjustColumnSizing: >DataTable/this.fnAdjustColumnSizing(bRedraw), fnClearTable: >DataTable/this.fnClearTable(bRedraw), fnClose: >DataTable/this.fnClose(nTr), 105 more… }

Comment: i am using datatable version 1.10 and above. Try to use this plugin and give try

Comment: Hi Deep. I'm using datatable 1.10.15 with jquery 2.2.4. Still i get table.rows is not a function even with .DataTable wit a "D".

Comment: Try to use exact code of mine. And also update your post with code you are using.

Comment: I've used the jquery links from your fiddle and he doesn't complain but return and empty Object { } for count. I guess because I'm sourcing from the php file and not html.

Comment: I think above code is not working in server side processing because data is not there in table .`table().rows()` will work if table is populated. check this server side sample http://jsfiddle.net/582gbry9/

Comment: Hi Deep.
I have tested your code (http://jsfiddle.net/582gbry9/) and it works. I had to change my php to present json data differently.
Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks 2 u also. Idea was nice to link datatable(server side processing) data to highchart, I licked this idea . But its is not 100% accurate because still there is manual interaction of button. it should happen automatically. Still finding way to do so. Still If this answer helped, accept this answer as   [explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: I'm looking into removing the button like you said. And here is my php (partial)
    <?php
    $data = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result1) ) {
 $data[] = array(
 $rows[0],
 round($rows[1],3),
        round(((($rows[1] / 5.940) * 100) / 5.940), 2),
 $rows[2],
        round(($rows[1] + $rows[3] - $rows[2]) , 3),
 $rows[3],
        $rows[4],
        $rows[5],
        );
    }

    $return = array(
 "sEcho" => 1,
 "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
 "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
 "data"=>$data);

    echo json_encode($return);
    ?>

Comment: @Deep3015, How can I use this to get the sum instead of count?

Comment: @HatemHusam please frame new question