# Render Highcharts data table to separate container as chart via drawing API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

From the HighCharts documentation, I'm studying the example given here to be able to add and render a data table:

"CAN I ADD A DATA TABLE TO THE EXPORTED CHART?

Yes, with a little programming on top of the Highcharts data and drawing API you can draw a table. See http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/ for source code and live example."

I'm trying to figure out how to render the data table to a different container than the chart. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

From JS Fiddle:

```
/**
 * Create the data table
 */
Highcharts.drawTable = function() {

    // user options
    var tableTop = 310,
        colWidth = 100,
        tableLeft = 20,
        rowHeight = 20,
        cellPadding = 2.5,
        valueDecimals = 1,
        valueSuffix = ' °C';

    // internal variables
    var chart = this,
        series = chart.series,
        renderer = chart.renderer,
        cellLeft = tableLeft;

    // draw category labels
    $.each(chart.xAxis[0].categories, function(i, name) {
        renderer.text(
            name, 
            cellLeft + cellPadding, 
            tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
        )
        .css({
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        })       
        .add();
    });

    $.each(series, function(i, serie) {
        cellLeft += colWidth;

        // Apply the cell text
        renderer.text(
                serie.name,
                cellLeft - cellPadding + colWidth, 
                tableTop + rowHeight - cellPadding
            )
            .attr({
                align: 'right'
            })
            .css({
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            })
            .add();

        $.each(serie.data, function(row, point) {

            // Apply the cell text
            renderer.text(
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, valueDecimals) + valueSuffix, 
                    cellLeft + colWidth - cellPadding, 
                    tableTop + (row + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
                )
                .attr({
                    align: 'right'
                })
                .add();

            // horizontal lines
            if (row == 0) {
                Highcharts.tableLine( // top
                    renderer,
                    tableLeft, 
                    tableTop + cellPadding,
                    cellLeft + colWidth, 
                    tableTop + cellPadding
                );
                Highcharts.tableLine( // bottom
                    renderer,
                    tableLeft, 
                    tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding,
                    cellLeft + colWidth, 
                    tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
                );
            }
            // horizontal line
            Highcharts.tableLine(
                renderer,
                tableLeft, 
                tableTop + row * rowHeight + rowHeight + cellPadding,
                cellLeft + colWidth, 
                tableTop + row * rowHeight + rowHeight + cellPadding
            );

        });

        // vertical lines        
        if (i == 0) { // left table border  
            Highcharts.tableLine(
                renderer,
                tableLeft, 
                tableTop + cellPadding,
                tableLeft, 
                tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
            );
        }

        Highcharts.tableLine(
            renderer,
            cellLeft, 
            tableTop + cellPadding,
            cellLeft, 
            tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
        );

        if (i == series.length - 1) { // right table border    

            Highcharts.tableLine(
                renderer,
                cellLeft + colWidth, 
                tableTop + cellPadding,
                cellLeft + colWidth, 
                tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
            );
        }

    });


};

/**
 * Draw a single line in the table
 */
Highcharts.tableLine = function (renderer, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    renderer.path(['M', x1, y1, 'L', x2, y2])
        .attr({
            'stroke': 'silver',
            'stroke-width': 1
        })
        .add();
}


    renderer.path(['M', x1, y1, 'L', x2, y2])
        .attr({
            'stroke': 'silver',
            'stroke-width': 1
        })
        .add();
}
```

Comment: In addition to what @Deep3015 said, you can use html2canvas for example, to export both chart and table at once. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wmgjqL6j/.

Comment: Interesting; I like the forEach to update visibility! I also asked this to @Deep3015, any way to make the Highcharts.drawTable options responsive and/or filterable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to render table in different container. So for this you can use chart in two containers with same code in example. Only difference is you have to hide chart in second container and load table functions.

```
 window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container2',
        events: {
            load: Highcharts.drawTable,
        },
        borderWidth: 2
    },
     title: {
        text: ''
    },
    
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        visible:false
    },
    
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        visible:false
    },

    legend: {
       enabled:false
    },

   series: [{
         name: 'Tokyo',
         data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
         visible:false
      }, {
         name: 'New York',
         data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5],
         visible:false
      }, {
         name: 'Berlin',
         data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0],
         visible:false
      }, {
         name: 'London',
         data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8],
         visible:false
      }]
    })
window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            //load: Highcharts.drawTable
        },
        borderWidth: 2
    },
    
    title: {
        text: 'Average monthly temperatures'
    },
    
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        }
    },

    legend: {
        //y: -300
    },

    series: [{
         name: 'Tokyo',
         data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
      }, {
         name: 'New York',
         data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
      }, {
         name: 'Berlin',
         data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
      }, {
         name: 'London',
         data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
      }]
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5mkx80h/) demo

**To Do** Adjust container css based on requirements

Comment: Works; thanks! As a follow-up question, any way to make the Highcharts.drawTable options responsive and/or filterable?

Comment: check my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45731220/3898339) it is based on jquery datatables.there jsfiddle example search is not working. but it works when properly done in real environment. Hope this helps